# How to have some math variables and subscripts/indices in serif and the rest of variables in sans serif?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif, math-fonts

I am writing a paper in which 99% of the variables involved are in frequency domain (not related to the question) and the rest of them are in time domain. I used the regular serif font for the majority of the variables as you would without any special command. For the 1% i wanted in san serif, I included the following (found somewhere on tex.stackexchange) at the beginning of the document:

```
\usepackage{sansmath,etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}
\appto{\sffamily}{\sansmath}
\appto{\rmfamily}{\unsansmath}
```

And then whichever variable I wanted to be in san serif i simply wrote `\mathsf{}` before that. Now my advisor wants me to flip that for whatever reason, i.e. have the 99% of the variables in san serif and the other 1% in serif. I included the following at the beginning now:

```
\usepackage{sfmath}
```

And that made san serif the default for all the variables. My question now is that is there any way I can have superscripts/subscripts/indexing in serif without having to go and include a pre-defined/my own command at each location? And I would also like to change those remaining 1% to serif. What do i do for that?

Not quite sure if i need a MWE with this question or not. Could cook up something if needed. Thanks for your help!

Adding a MWE as suggested:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{sfmath}

\begin{document}

\title{MWE}
\maketitle

With the inclusion of the `sfmath' package all variables are now in san serif: $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{q}_n = [q_{1,n} , \dots , q_{K,n}]^\text{T}$ are examples.  However, I do not want the subscripts to be in sans serif. Similarly there might be situation where i have variables as superscripts or as indices (for example: $(i,j)$) which i do not in sans serif. And i won't like to define a command and then include that at each position a sub/super script is used. The paper is quite long and has a lot of maths to do that.

Secondly, I want this variable: $\mathbf{Y}$ to be in serif. This i can do manually since there are only a few of these variables. How do i do that?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Although you've given a good description of your problem, a potential helper would still have to invent an example to experiment with.  If you provide a MWE that can be copied and pasted, it will be much easier for someone to help.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton! I added a MWE showing the different cases as suggested.